# Add ALL to list of values in a Paginated report parameter and filter all values

Tags: parameters, powerbi, dax, powerbi-paginated-reports

I am new to Power BI paginated reports.

I have a report where it has 9 parameters.

[image]

By default all these parameters are mandatory.

But, I would like to have **ALL** as by default selection in my parameters.
So I have changed my DAX for one of parameter dataset **Project Manager** as below.

```
 EVALUATE
 UNION
 (
 DISTINCT(SELECTCOLUMNS(Projects, "Top_ProjectManager","ALL"))
 ,
 SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
 Projects[Top_ProjectManager],
 KEEPFILTERS( FILTER( ALL( Projects[Top_ProjectManager] ), NOT( ISBLANK( 
 Projects[Top_ProjectManager] ))))
 )
 )
```

Under parameters properties I have set default value as ALL
[image]

Now I am able to see the Auto selected value of each parameter as ALL.
[image]

But when I click on view report it is showing blank report.

I need to bind this ALL as default and show the data in report for all of project managers whenever it is selected.

The filters in Master Dataset query I have given as

```
FILTER(VALUES(Projects[Top_ProjectManager]), (Projects[Top_ProjectManager] = @ProjectManager)),
FILTER(VALUES(Projects[ProjectManager]), (Projects[ProjectManager]=@SubProjectManager )),
FILTER(VALUES(Projects[Top_MarketName]), (Projects[Top_MarketName]=@ProjectMarket )),
FILTER(VALUES(Projects[Top_PracDiscName]), (Projects[Top_PracDiscName]=@ProjectPracDisc ))
```

And this is how the dataset parameters been set.

[image]

Could you please correct me how I can view the report when the parameter is selected ALL.

Please help.

Thanks,
Mohan V.

Answer (score 0):

try the Filter like this: DEFINE

```
VAR Parameter = @Parameter

FILTER (
        VALUES ( Tbl[Fld] ),
        OR (
            Parameter = "ALL",
            PATHCONTAINS (
                SUBSTITUTE (
                    SUBSTITUTE ( SUBSTITUTE ( Parameter, "{", "" ), "}", "" ),
                    ",",
                    "|"
                ),
                Tbl[Fld]
            )
        )
    )
```